# How can I move an element to where the cursor is?

Tags: qt, widget, move, qtextcursor

How can I move an element to where the cursor is?
For example: I want to move the combobox to the position of the cursor in the text box of the element.

[image]

Comment: This is the same question you [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578489/i-want-to-change-the-selected-word-qt).  Rather than asking the same question again you'd be better off editing the original to address the points raised in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QWidget::move(int x, int y)` to move any widget to the cursor's position: `QCursor::pos()`